# Why did the PEER1 join the channel failure?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Followed the [tutorials](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html), when I trying to bring the network up with the following command `./byfn.sh -m up`, I got an error:

```
Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10000'
Continue (y/n)?y
proceeding ...
...
 ____    _____      _      ____    _____ 
/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |  
 ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |  
|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|  

Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test
...
===================== PEER0 joined on the channel "mychannel" 

===================== 

2017-09-25 06:58:27.580 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PER:404 - Error trying to connect to local peer
...
/opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:192 runtime.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2087 runtime.goexit
Caused by: x509: certificate is valid for peer0.org1.example.com, peer0, not peer1.org1.example.com
Usage:
  peer channel join [flags]

Flags:
  -b, --blockpath string   Path to file containing genesis block
  ...
```

I have checked the software version and they should be correct.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin HMacBook-Pro.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.07.0-ce-rc2
 API version:  1.31
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   36ce605
 Built:        Mon Aug  7 23:43:03 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.07.0-ce-rc2
 API version:  1.31 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   36ce605
 Built:        Mon Aug  7 23:48:34 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.15.0, build e12f3b9
docker-py version: 2.4.2
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016

$ node -v
v6.9.5

$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

And the docker info:

```
$ docker images | grep hyper
hyperledger/fabric-ca                    latest              7e53be14f804        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                    x86_64-1.0.2        7e53be14f804        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                 latest              ba9750b2565d        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                 x86_64-1.0.2        ba9750b2565d        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb               latest              3f922f54bd68        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb               x86_64-1.0.2        3f922f54bd68        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                 latest              0b4b1d249e65        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                 x86_64-1.0.2        0b4b1d249e65        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper             latest              1efb063147d3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper             x86_64-1.0.2        1efb063147d3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer               latest              6efd17e86e65        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer               x86_64-1.0.2        6efd17e86e65        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                  latest              0e2ed51971c9        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                  x86_64-1.0.2        0e2ed51971c9        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv               latest              0be45dbd7ff4        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv               x86_64-1.0.2        0be45dbd7ff4        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                 latest              d0f166e1a89e        3 weeks ago         1.28GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                 x86_64-1.0.2        d0f166e1a89e        3 weeks ago         1.28GB

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
3e12dd9ea9ac        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash -c './s..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                       cli
942ff1a22c17        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
9e75ab80502d        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
67a545f37af1        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
a4dedbab71fa        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
a5fb0662c227        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
```

why? How should I fix it? Need Your Help!

I tried to down and up the network (`./byfn.sh -m down`, `./byfn.sh -m up`), it didn't work. Then, I deleted all docker images and all locale files in the path $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples, and the error was the same.

Comment: I downloaded a bootstrap file from [githubusercontent](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.2.sh)

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: x509: certificate is valid for peer0.org1.example.com,
>   peer0, not peer1.org1.example.com

This is caused because you're trying to connect to peer1.org1.example.com
but the peer that's actually there, is peer0.org1.example.com

This is probably because a wrong environment variable CORE_PEER_ADDRESS.
Print it in the script just before and see for yourself.

Comment: Last night I tracked the code `script/script.sh` and I found you were right.
First execute the command `peer chaincode join ...`, the value of CORE_PEER_ADDRESS is peer0.org1.example.com; The second time the value of CORE_PEER_ADDRESS is peer1.org1.example.com, because it resets the value of CORE_PEER_ADDRESS. Is this not normal?           But I have not modified the code, and the tutorial Doc did not let me modify this value? How can I solve this problem continue to finish byfn demo?

Comment: what do you mean by "continue to finish byfn demo" ?

Comment: I mean run the demo [BYFN](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html). Something is wrong, it can't work correctly. And I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I Just ran byfn -m up and the join channel (and the rest) worked for me...)

Do you want to contact me on http://chat.hyperledger.org/ (my user is yacovm too) ? We can do a google hangout or something and solve it